# Is there any way to get the Faderator in Fallout: New Vegas on the 360?

Tags: xbox-360, fallout-new-vegas

The [Faderator](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_Faderator) is a piece of cut content in the Fallout: New Vegas addon Dead Money. It's retrievable using console commands on the PC, but I'm not running F:NV on the PC; I'd like to get at this content (and possibly other cut content) on the Xbox 360.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You would have to use a modded 360 and a gamesave-editing tool. There's no legit way.

Answer (score 3):

There are save editors you can use by transferring the save files to be edited onto a USB flash drive. It does not void warranty and you can't get in trouble with Microsoft because you haven't modified the 360 itself.

I have done it for Fallout 3 and am running around with the cut content grenade launcher.

Comment: Hey John, welcome to the site. In the future, please don't post your contact information telling them to contact you for more info, since if this answer needs more info it would be better for other people who have this question to also see it when they come across this answer, rather than have it stashed in some private email exchange.